# Unrecognized field in Android JSon deserialization

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, unmarshalling

I have a Json string been returned from my test server, the Android app is getting this fine but when I try to move it into an object using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter it fails on the one field that is a List.

Can't seem to figure out why, have tried numerous annotations without success and the error is get is:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "HourlySalesFigures" (class org.springframework.android.showcase.DayData), 
not marked as ignorable (15 known properties: , "nextDate", "totalLoyalty", "previousDate", "totalCheque", "numberOfLoyaltySales", "totalGrand", "numberOfChequeSales", "hourlySalesFigures", "totalCard", "totalCash", "totalCharge" [truncated]])
```

Returned JSon data:

```
{"HourlySalesFigures":[{"hour":0,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":1,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":2,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":3,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":4,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":5,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":6,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":7,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":8,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":9,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0},{"hour":10,"numberOfSales":4,"totalOfSales":548},{"hour":11,"numberOfSales":1,"totalOfSales":3},{"hour":12,"numberOfSales":7,"totalOfSales":209.5},{"hour":13,"numberOfSales":8,"totalOfSales":528.4},{"hour":14,"numberOfSales":13,"totalOfSales":1196.8},{"hour":15,"numberOfSales":9,"totalOfSales":1422.2},{"hour":16,"numberOfSales":12,"totalOfSales":321.5},{"hour":17,"numberOfSales":22,"totalOfSales":493.5},{"hour":18,"numberOfSales":21,"totalOfSales":740.5},{"hour":19,"numberOfSales":28,"totalOfSales":1180.5},{"hour":20,"numberOfSales":8,"totalOfSales":377.5},{"hour":21,"numberOfSales":9,"totalOfSales":859.8},{"hour":22,"numberOfSales":28,"totalOfSales":11193.8},{"hour":23,"numberOfSales":1,"totalOfSales":107}],"TargetDate":"2013/02/13","PreviousDate":"2013/02/12","NextDate":"2013/02/14","NumberOfCashSales":126,"TotalCash":8432.1,"NumberOfCardSales":23,"TotalCard":9775.9,"NumberOfChequeSales":0,"TotalCheque":0,"NumberOfLoyaltySales":0,"TotalLoyalty":0,"NumberOfChargeSales":22,"TotalCharge":974.0,"TotalGrand":19182.0}
```

Java objects I am trying to put this into are (Please note I have left out the getters and setters for brevity)

DayData class

```
@Root
public class DayData {

@ElementList(name="HourlySalesFigures", inline=true)
protected List<HourSalesItem> hourlySalesFigures;

@Element(name="TargetDate")
protected String targetDate;
@Element(name="PreviousDate")
protected String previousDate;
@Element(name="NextDate")
protected String nextDate;
@Element(name="NumberOfCashSales")
protected int numberOfCashSales;
@Element(name="TotalCash")
protected double totalCash;
@Element(name="NumberOfCardSales")
protected int numberOfCardSales;
@Element(name="TotalCard")
protected double totalCard;
@Element(name="NumberOfChequeSales")
protected int numberOfChequeSales;
@Element(name="TotalCheque")
protected double totalCheque;
@Element(name="NumberOfLoyaltySales")
protected int numberOfLoyaltySales;
@Element(name="TotalLoyalty")
protected double totalLoyalty;
@Element(name="NumberOfChargeSales")
protected int numberOfChargeSales;
@Element(name="TotalCharge")
protected double totalCharge;
@Element(name="TotalGrand")
protected double totalGrand;

public DayData(List<HourSalesItem> HourlySalesFigures, String targetDate, String previousDate, String nextDate, int numberOfCashSales, double totalCash, int numberOfCardSales, double totalCard, int numberOfChequeSales, double totalCheque, int numberOfLoyaltySales, double totalLoyalty, int numberOfChargeSales, double totalCharge, double totalGrand) {
    this.hourlySalesFigures = HourlySalesFigures;
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
    this.previousDate = previousDate;
    this.nextDate = nextDate;
    this.numberOfCashSales = numberOfCashSales;
    this.totalCash = totalCash;
    this.numberOfCardSales = numberOfCardSales;
    this.totalCard = totalCard;
    this.numberOfChequeSales = numberOfChequeSales;
    this.totalCheque = totalCheque;
    this.numberOfLoyaltySales = numberOfLoyaltySales;
    this.totalLoyalty = totalLoyalty;
    this.numberOfChargeSales = numberOfChargeSales;
    this.totalCharge = totalCharge;
    this.totalGrand = totalGrand;
}

public DayData()
{

}
}
```

HourSalesItem class

```
@Root
public class HourSalesItem{

@Element
private int hour;
@Element
private int numberOfSales;
@Element
private double totalOfSales;

public HourSalesItem(int hour, int numberOfSales, double totalOfSales) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.numberOfSales = numberOfSales;
    this.totalOfSales = totalOfSales;
}

public HourSalesItem(){

}
}
```

Comment: Try with renaming your vars. as HourlySalesFigures, TargetDate etc.

Comment: Did think of that, hence the @Element(name="TotalGrand") annotations. But renamed the variables anyway and retried, same error.

Comment: DayData constructor dont have HourlySalesFigures param in CamelCase, maybe that can be the issue? I'm not sure, just guessing.

Comment: Changed constructor to use Upper case as per 'HourlySalesFigures' in both the argument and constructor body, same thing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Server REST was returning Json with uppercase camel humped variables, e.g.

```
TotalGrand
```

renamed to

```
totalGrand
```

solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @JsonIgnore property to ignore the fields that you are not handling/parsing in your code. Might be it would resolve the issue. If you have a different JSON parsing API then you just need to search how to ignore JSON key?

Comment: The sample JSON shown in my question above will always return hourlySalesFigures with 24 items within, they will simply be set to zero if not used so there should not be any data returned which is never used. Not sure if this impacts your answer ?

Comment: Tried it anyway, didn't work and gave me the same error as original.

Comment: See my second answer with formatted JSON file. If it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

See  `{"hour":0,"numberOfSales":0,"totalOfSales":0}`

A JSON file is the `{"Key":"value"}` pair. According to Software's language it only understands string type of Key and string type of value. So try to change it as

```
{"hour":0,"numberOfSales":"0","totalOfSales":"0"}
```

and parse it accordingly on your end.

*I give it as second answer because of JSON formatting.*